# Haskell: Is there an operator like this: (<$$>) :: Functor f => f a -> (a -> b) -> f b

Tags: haskell

Finding out that map and flat map in Haskell could be performed the this way,

```
xs >>= f          ≃ flatMap f xs
xs >>= return . f ≃ map f xs
```

I thought it would be convenient if we have such an operator

```
(<$$>) :: Functor f => f a -> (a -> b) -> f b
f <$$> fn = fn <$> f
```

so that map could be expressed more tidily:

```
xs >>=  f ≃ flatMap f xs
xs <$$> f ≃ map f xs
```

Does such an operator exist in Haskell's standard library?

Comment: Running [this query](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3A%3A+Functor+f+%3D%3E+f+a+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+f+b+%2Bbase) in Hoogle does not return an exact match. I don't think there is, unfortunately.

Comment: yes, I did exactly the same query but found nothing: thus came this question

Comment: If Hoogle doesn't find anything, [try Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=Functor+f+%3D%3E+f+a+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+f+b) (which searches more packages by default). There's nothing in the standard library, but there are many `<&>`s in various libs.

Comment: Downvoter, could you please leave a comment so that I could know how to improve my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not anywhere in the `base` package. The most commonly used library that exports this function is [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens), [as `<&>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Operators.html#v:-60--38--62-).

Comment: [microlens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/microlens) also has this function.

Answer (score 2):

Note also that, as often to flip arguments, operator sections may be "enough" and may perhaps preserve readability by limiting the introduction of new operators:

```
> :{
| (<$> Just 0) $ \x ->
|   x + 1 + 1 + 1
|     + 1 + 1 + 1
|     + 1 + 1 + 1
|     + 1 + 1 + 1
| :}
Just 12
```

Comment: This doesn't use `TupleSections` (or tuples for that matter). It is just an operator section, which requires no extension.